# opencv ReprojectImageto3D gives values tending to infinity

Tags: python, opencv, depth, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I am using stereocalibrate and stereorectify to get the Q matrix.
I am giving this as input to cv.ReprojectImageto3D to get the depth map.
But when I try to show the results, many values are calculated as infinity.

Do I need to change or scale anything before reprojecting. And is the result which we get in pixels?

```
    (roi1,roi2) = cv.StereoRectify(camMatrix1, camMatrix2, d1, d2,(320,240), r, t, r1, r2, p1, p2, q, cv.CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, -1, (0, 0))
    np.savetxt('Q_mat.txt',q)
    disparity  = getDisparity(img_r, img_l, "BM")
    disp = cv.fromarray(disparity)
    Image = cv.CreateMat(disp.rows, disp.cols, cv.CV_32FC3)
    Q = np.loadtxt('Q_mat.txt')
    Q = np.reshape(Q,(4,4))
    Q1 = cv.fromarray(Q)
    cv.ReprojectImageTo3D(disp, Image, Q1, 0)
```

link to image:
 http://i43.tinypic.com/2gtau5s.png

[image]
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Hi. You might want to post some sample code to make it easier for others to help you. Also, posting your test images would also help.

Comment: Hi I added the code, am not able to include Images.

Comment: Just Post the link to the image and someone can edit it in properly.

Comment: posted the link to the image